# SVG With Object Tag Doesn't Scale In Safari

Tags: html, css, svg

I have two svg images on my home page that are inside object tags. They scale beautifully when the browser is resized in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari they won't scale, they just get get off. I have tried making adjustments to the width and height of the svg image itself but that just causes the svg to become too large on tablet size screens. I've searched and searched for a solution, but have yet to find one. While I wish there was a way to just target Safari since it works great in both Chrome and Firefox, if anyone can offer some help with this I would greatly appreciate it.

My html code for one of the svg images:

```
    <a href="about.html">
            <div class="svg-container">
                <object class="img-responsive" type="image/svg+xml" 
                data="images/portrait-md.svg" >
               <img src="images/portrait-md.png" />
                </object>
           </div>
        </a>
```

The css I have used for the div container class:

```
    .svg-container {
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .svg-container object {
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .img-responsive {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
     }
```

My site: http://rachelhkay.com

Comment: Update to my problem. Even though the svg container and object tags are scaling for some weird reason the svg itself will not scale in Safari. Even if I set a 100% width and height on the svg itself the svg will not scale. I've attempted to add to the .svg-container object {width: 100%; display: block; height: auto; position: relative;} and also removed overflow: hidden and position: relative from the .svg-container class. Problem is that in doing so the svg just won't scale in height but does scale in width. Why won't the svg itself scale in Safari yet the container will?

Answer (score 0):

> You can make the width and height of the svg 100% in css.

```
svg {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

> For more information. Visit this link below, and see if that helps.
>
> http://benfrain.com/attempting-to-fix-responsive-svgs-in-desktop-safari/

Comment: I did look into that option but wasn't too sure how to implement it. The img-responsive class has a max-width of 100% to ensure the images scale. The .svg-container I have surrounding the object tag helped to get Chrome to stop cutting off the images as Safari seems to now be doing. Using svg is still a bit of a learning process for me, but much better quality than png.